# how to get multi touch event from SetWindowsHookEx in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have found a way to separate touch and mouse events on wpf project. the issue I have now is that my `hookProc()` seems to be getting only the first touch events. when there are more than 2 touches on the screen, only the first touch has response from `hookProc()`. I want to be able to support multi touch in my application.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc (int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
const uint MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH = 0xFF515700;

private LowLevelMouseProc _proc = hookProc;

private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

public void SetHook()
{
    IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _proc, hInstance, 0);
}

public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{

    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT info = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

    uint extraInfo = (uint)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt32();
    if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("this is touch");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("this is mouse");
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetHook();
}
```